# single mysql query that show a particular parent and child value

Tags: mysql, hierarchy

I am facing problem to show a particular parent child value and under all child value as a relationship. I have created single table `tree` and three column `id`, `child` and `parent`.

I created a tree relationship but I don't understand how to fetch a particular parent child and his child and his child value for tree. Can you help me?

Comment: do you want to fetch a value and all his descendants? Can you add the content of a table for a simple tree? Do you have any constraints on your table? what mysql version are you using? Can you show the statements that adds/deletes a node to/of the tree? You are writing about ships but I think you want to write about relationships.

Answer (score 0):

By the way the same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query#answer-20216006) has been already asked/answered and I would recommand you reading the [article](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/) of the answer.

The article propose another solution which is less expensive to list parent/children : "The Nested Set Model" method which use these columns : id, left, right. 
You will have to manage by yourself (or by your application) the left/right value.